# How to cite a company that gave the data and formulated a problem to be solved in a competition?

Tags: publications, citations, paper-submission, citation-style

So recently there was a data science competition and we learned and made a good algorithm which can be published as a case study. So how can I cite the Data source and the really good score metric that was also given by the company which organiszed the competition? Yes the data has been made public and free to use but the scoring metric that was given was in a document given during the competition has no public document is available for it. Yes the link for the competition also exist.

Thanks this is my first paper and im super confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include an Acknowledgements section in which you thank the company for the data and the contest as appropriate. You can include, there, a link to the data, etc.

It is probably unnecessary to even mention the scoring metric for purposes of citation. It is possible that the company wants it kept private if they haven't published it.

Comment: "It is probably unnecessary to even mention the scoring metric for purposes of citation" - OP's question seems to imply that the scoring metric is pretty important in their results. Presumably their conclusions are based on performance based on that metric or something along those lines. So it'll be pretty important that they work out whether this is meant to be private, because that probably means their entire work is meant to be private, which seems to me like a huge problem but maybe it's a liability you encounter when entering a competition like this.

Comment: Yeah the scoring metric they gave is important as it scores/evaluates the model and the algorithm we made, and yes the company said that it is okay sharing it during the competition, Thanks, I'll add the data source and thank the company for the metric in the acknowledgement section.

Answer (score 2):

You can cite websites and documents (even private ones) in the usual way. You should acknowledge the organiser for posing the question that your algorithm addresses (since it isn't a contribution of yours).  The score is valuable when presented with the scoring metric (since readers can presumably only verify the score using the metric). That poses a problem, because the metric is private. Perhaps you can ask the organiser's permission to include the scoring metric.

Comment: I agree, I wanted to get them the credit, and yes the mathematical logic behind the metric is really good and simple, so it's a good idea to use it. as a solution stated above, I'll mention about it in the acknowledgement section.

Comment: @Sanx I've updated following your comment.